# How to add by +1 to indexes in a list

Tags: python, loops

I have a list with about 500 values, representing the last 500 weeks of values in LIST below. LIST_INDEX is this weeks index. BUT if I wanna travel back in time and see the the index for that period of time, let´s say LIST[134:144], instead of manually write 500 lines of code for each period of time, how can I do this task? I need it from LIST[0:10] TO LIST[490:500]

```
LIST = ["in this list there are about 500 values"]

CURRENT_VALUE = (LIST[-1])

LIST_INDEX = (CO_CURRENT_VALUE - min(LIST[197:207])) / (max(LIST[197:207])- min(LIST[197:207]))
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Where exactly are you stuck. Please also provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
LIST = ["in this list there are about 500 values"]
for i in range(490):
    print(LIST[i:i+10])
```